# I need a ticket counter that starts at a given value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner in web-development, I tried to make a counter for number of tickets purchased but I want it to start at a given value.

Mine always starts from 0, is there a way to make it happen?

Here is my Code:

I've tried using html/JS/CSS & jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
     ></script>
        <link href="newcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Tickets Counter</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container counter-section">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-3 counter-box">
                    
                    <div class="icon-box" ><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> </div>
                    <p class="counter">150</p>
                    <p>Tickets</p>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        
        <!---COUNTER----->
        
        <script src="jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
       <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script> 
       <script>
           jQuery(document).ready(function( $ )
           {
               $('.counter').counterUp({
                delay: 10,
                time: 1000
});
           });
       </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Acording to the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.counterup), you can do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.counter').counterUp({
        delay: 10,
        time: 1000,
        beginAt: 100
    });
});
```